# What does QE do in a modern agile web development environment?

Tags: agile, quality-assurance

What are the key tasks and responsibilities of the Quality Engineering group in a modern Agile web development group?

Comment: What is the reason you're asking this question or what is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @dzieciou - it looks like the OP is trying to build a question with a canonical answer because we tend to get a lot of questions along these lines. Voting to keep open because the key tasks/responsibilities tend to be similar and limited across environment.

Comment: @KatePaul Can you link those questions here? Still to me this is oferly broad. I would rather ask what are good books covering this topic. And the book of Lisa Cristina would be in the answers.

Comment: Lisa Crispin perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

- Review application and test code PRs*
- Document bugs in a bug tracking system
- Pair with developers on new feature tests
- Continually build business domain knowledge
- Investigate and fix Intermittent test failures
- Write new feature specs for existing functionality
- Refactor existing tests to improve test code quality
- Write and configure mobile specific test automation
- Document procedures and workflows in wikis for all
- Manually test staging before production deployments
- Get feedback from real users to drive usability efforts
- Develop tools and infrastructure to test mobile devices
- Aid in defining and monitoring company quality metrics
- Pair with developers on test plans for new features and bugs
- Champion and evangelize good quality development practices
- Contribute to Agile processes from Sprint Planning to Retrospectives
- Champion good quality practices through presentations and Lunch and Learns
- Champion and demonstrate accessibility and usability issues and good practices
- Ensures all the testing quadrants are covered: Unit, Functional, Performance and Exploratory

* Pull Requests

Answer (score 1):

Some of the different things I do on a regular basis other than standard 'QA'

- Act as a flex developer
- Review Check ins and monitor the code base
- Groom stories
- Focus the team's efforts
- Optimize the team's time
- Demonstrate changes to end users
- Act as liaison for the team
- Create release documentation
- Create release procedure and steps
- Verify release
- Ensure backlog is clean and prioritized
- Deep understanding of all stories (Business and Tech side)
- Deep understanding of all integration points
- Work with other teams regarding integrations

Comment: I know who  Flex developer is, but "flex developer"?

Comment: A developer when needed essentially.

Comment: Yeah there is Flex which is a powerful, open source application framework, but here we are just talking about flex as in flexibility, i.e. ability to change